# How to show messages from InputRequired in flask-wtforms

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

In this Script, I set the message for `InputRequired` in `wtforms.validator` to showing error. also, I giving max and min for a length of character. But these arguments not working.

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, IntegerField, SubmitField,StringField
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError, Length, EqualTo, InputRequired, Email

class Login(FlaskForm):
    email =StringField(validators=[InputRequired(message = 'please input something'), Length(min=10, max=20), Email(message='this is not email')])
    password = PasswordField(validators=[InputRequired(message='please input something'), Length(min=8, max=20, message='you must be input more than 8 character')])
    submit = SubmitField('Enter')

class Register(FlaskForm):
    email =StringField(validators=[InputRequired(message = 'please input something'), Length(min=10, max=20), Email(message='this is not email')])
    phone = IntegerField(validators=[InputRequired(message='please input something')])
    password = PasswordField(validators=[InputRequired(message='please input something'), Length(min=8, max=20, message='you must be input more than 8 character')])
    submit = SubmitField('Enter')
```

This Script is `login.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h3>this is Home page</h3>
<form action="#">
    <!-- {{forlogin.hidden_tag()}} -->
    {{forlogin.email(placeholder="email")}}
    <br>
    {{forlogin.password(placeholder="password")}}
    <br>
    {{forlogin.submit}}
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Honestly, No. I edited my question to show login.html. please checking again

Answer (score 1):

From the Field class documentation in WTForms documentation:

> errors
>
> ```
> If validate encounters any errors, they will be inserted into this list.
> ```

So to show the errors, you have to show the items in the list on your page:

```
   <form action="#">
        {{login.email(placeholder="email")}}{% for error in login.email.errors %} {{ error }} {% endfor%}
   </form>
```

I do not know what the `for` was meant to do between the double braces, I removed it. It caused errors in Jinja2.